# バギングした決定木を可視化したいのにエラーが出る

Tags: python, 機械学習

バギングした決定木を可視化したいです。
以下のようなコードを書きましたが

```
#決定木モデルとバギングの設定
model=BaggingClassifier(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0), n_estimators=100, random_state=0) 
#モデルの構築
scores = {}
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
#可視化
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model,out_file=None,feature_names=["TolX"],class_names=["C1","good","C5,D5"],filled=True, rounded=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
```

modelのfitはしているはずなのに次のようなエラーが出て図が作成できません。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rf.py", line 79, in <module>
    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model,feature_names=["Tol"],class_names=["C1","good","C5,D5"],filled=True, rounded=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/export.py", line 757, in export_graphviz
    check_is_fitted(decision_tree, 'tree_')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 914, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

ちなみにBaggingClassifierを使う前はtree.DecisionTreeClassifierで同様の方法で可視化成功できていました。

Comment: `model.estimators_` に `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` インスタンスが格納されていますので(`n_estimators=100` と指定しているので 100 個のインスタンス)、例えば `dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model.estimators_[0], ...)` などとします。

Comment: @metropolis 様ありがとうございます。ランダムフォレストでも同様の可視化をしたいのですがエラーが出ます。こちらの質問にもお答えいただけないでしょうか。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62490/バギングしたランダムフォレストの決定木を表示したい